# Lightsimplebox gallery -> CSS/JS integration, hover, image and description

Tags: javascript, css, gallery, galleryview

I need your help about 2 problems I can't resolve on the light simple box.
With a friend, we adding to my gallery a div-caption with a title and a description at the bottom of my illustrations. Till more 3 weeks I spend on problems and I didn't find a solution. I tried to style with a table / table-caption ... but it didn't work.

To know: I'm starting to coding and my js experiences are very small, I'll you can learn me something.

1 / A hover-span appear on my miniatures like that: http://www.zupimages.net/up/17/30/8268.png
I thought to delete that on hover mouse but a display: none will delete my description! Or a method to create a countdown only for the hover (and making this invisible ._. ).

2 / JS gallery resize the image and the problem is ... if my description is long, the text take all part of invisible margin (if the illustration is on format layout): http://www.zupimages.net/up/17/30/3mr1.png
I needed to add a scrollbar to this other the description couldn't be read.

**My code:**

```
<div class="sl-image scrollbar style-8"> <img src="/image.jpg" style="width: (calculted by js);"> <div class="sl-caption pos-bottom"> <span>Title</span> <p>Description here </p> </div> </div>
```

Btw, thanks! :c

Comment: Share your code as a text format here not image. Otherwise, edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My code is like that: '<div class="sl-image scrollbar style-8">
<img src="/image.jpg" style="width: (calculted by js);">
<div class="sl-caption pos-bottom">
<span>Title</span>
<p>Description here </p>
</div>
</div>'